# Run autocmd when creating/deleting a buffer

Tags: buffers, autocmd

I have two functions `tex#PDFOpen()` and `tex#PDFClose()` to automatically open and close the pdf file created by a TeX document.

The way I assign them to autocommands is via the following autogroup in `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
augroup TeXGroup
  autocmd BufEnter <buffer> call tex#PDFOpen()
  autocmd BufUnload <buffer> call tex#PDFClose()
augroup END
```

Now if I open a .tex file `tex#PDFOpen()` is called, but if edit another buffer with `:e ...`, then `tex#PDFClose()` is called, which I don't want. If I switch back to the buffer with the .tex file, `tex#PDFOpen()` is called again, which I also don't want.

Basically, `tex#PDFOpen()` should only be called

1. on startup, if the argument of `nvim` is a .tex file;
2. when editing a .tex file in a new buffer.

Similarly, `tex#PDFClose()` should only be called

1. on exit, if one of the buffers contains a .tex file;
2. when closing a buffer with a .tex file with `:bd`.

I've tried every event listed [here](https://tech.saigonist.com/b/code/list-all-vim-script-events.html), but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that for some reason people like to use `:bdelete` to close buffers. That's a very strange practice, IMO. Let's recall what is that `:bdelete` all about.

A buffer in Vim can 1) exist (`bufexists()` returns true); 2) be "loaded" (`bufloaded()` returns true), and 3) be "listed" (`buflisted()` returns true). Please, note that (2) and (3) are fully independent one of another, and any combination of (2) and (3) is legal for any buffer.

"Loaded" indicates that the buffer already has some contents attached and needs not to be read from disk (or whatever else) before showing it in some window. However, in practice one may also view an "unloaded" buffer as some sort of MRU record (a number, file name, some bookmarks and such, but no content at all).

At the same time the "listed" flag only indicates that the buffer should appear in the output of `:ls` command. But note that even if some buffer is unlisted, it still exists (and can even be "loaded") and can be seen in the output of `:ls!`.

Now `:bdelete` is basically a shortcut for `:bunload` and `:set nobuflisted` together. Moreover, the event called `BufDelete` is actually triggered when some buffer is set to `nobuflisted`, no matter if it's loaded or not. Read `:h BufDelete` carefully, it's all written there!

So `:bdelete` is a useless command, IMO. One "hides" buffers when he doesn't need to work on them anymore; one also "unloads" buffers to spare a bit of RAM; and on rare occasions one also "wipes" buffers to clean up some editing history. But what's good in `:bdelete` is beyond my reach.

So it really looks strange and counter-intuitive to require `:bdelete` (and to rely ultimately on `buflisted`) in this case. And on the other hand it seems quite okay to trap `BufUnload` as it was done.

Now to the question "why it doesn't work as I expect". The problem is that when your buffer gets hidden (i.e. not shown in any open window anymore) for any reason, Vim must decide what to do with the loaded content (after all, it takes some RAM and Vim is really peculiar about that).

So the first thing Vim inspects is a buffer-local `:h 'bufhide'` option, and if it's empty then it's a global `:h 'hidden'` option. By default nothing is set, and so Vim disposes the buffer content to save a couple of RAM bytes (and this is where `BufUnload` is triggered).

Now you want to keep some "pdf"-file open for a long time, and it's only natural to assume that you are also keen to keep "tex"-file loaded in memory too. To achieve this you should either globally `:set hidden` to keep all files in memory as long as possible (not a problem nowadays, is it?), or set it for tex files only:

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim

```
setlocal bufhide=hidden
```

Now to trigger `BufUnload` for real you need `:quit!`, `ZQ` or `:bunload` (these commands always unload buffer contents, no matter what your options are). While `:quit`, `:xit`, `ZZ` etc. etc. will keep "tex" in memory, and so "pdf" remains open too.

Comment: But if I open a tex document and then open another file with `:e `, even if I use `:q!` the pdf remains open. I don't know if it's because the function isn't called at all, or if it's called but it fails. The idea I had (and I might very well be wrong) is that if I have 5 buffers open then quit, neovim would trigger a `BufUnload` for every buffer, and on the `*.tex` buffers that event would then execute the function to close the pdf file relative to that buffer. Btw, I've moved the `TeXGroup` autogroup to the main `init.vim` file as @filbranden suggested.

Comment: @noibe `if I have 5 buffers open then quit, neovim would trigger a BufUnload for every buffer` How is that so?! `:q[!]` quits an active buffer only. If you want to close a few specific (say, *.tex) buffers you have to write such command yourself.

Comment: Oh, I thought neovim would quit all the buffers on exit. What happens to the other (non active) ones, do they remain in memory?

Comment: @noibe I don't understand you. `:quit` closes the current window. And if it was the last one, it also exits Vim. In this case all buffers are unloaded, of course. That's all written in the help system.

Comment: Nevermind, I understood what's not working. The problem is that in `tex#PDFClose()` I use `let filepath = expand('%:p')` to get the filepath of the tex file, however when I quit that returns the filepath of the file in the active buffer. I need to pass the filepath of the file that triggered the autocommand to that function. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @noibe Pretty standard thing with autocommands. Read `:h BufUnload`, it's all written there too. And as I see, @filbranden also mentioned that in his answer.

Comment: @Matt May ask one question, for my situation, if I open two file, the previous file will be hidden(has `set hidden` in vimrc). Then if I quit vim, the BufUnload autocmd only works for the second file? Is it by design?

Comment: @roachsinai That was asked just above. `BufUnload` is triggered twice, but "a hidden" buffer is not made active.

Comment: @Matt thanks for reply. But I don't understrand you well. What do you mean `BufUnload` triggered twice? Does it mean triggered for each file? Is a documentation for hidden `buffer` not work with `BufUnload` I can't find it.

Comment: @roachsinai "Buffer" is not a "file", it's a memory chunk. "BufUnload" is triggered when memory is freed. As simple as that.

Comment: @Matt But I have quit Vim entirely! The memory should be freed, isn't it?

Comment: @roachsinai Yes, sure.

Comment: @Matt So, why "BufUnload" is not triggered? Could you tell me where I'm wrong about these things :(

Comment: @roachsinai It is triggered. I can't know what you're doing wrong. Read documentation, re-read the answers and the comments carefully, think, experiment, debug etc.etc.

Comment: @Matt my setting is `set hidden` and when I quit whole vim `BufUnload` trigger only for buffer not hidden.

Comment: @Math thanks for all your explanation! I'll check my setting again, again.

Comment: @roachsinai Read `:h BufUnload` carefully. Make sure you've understood everything mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you use `BufRead` to open the PDF and `BufDelete` to close it.

Note that this should be set up at a global context, and not on the ftplugin for the `tex` filetype.

Furthermore, you should match it by filename on `*.tex` (and other filenames you might want to match), rather than adding multiple per-buffer autocmd's attached to the filetype.

For example, try adding the following to your vimrc:

```
augroup TeXGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead *.tex call tex#PDFOpen()
  autocmd BufDelete *.tex call tex#PDFClose()
augroup END
```

Note that when the functions are called, the current buffer might no longer be the one with the `*.tex` file, so you might want to update your functions to take the file name as an argument and use `<afile>` (or `<abuf>`) to have them act on the correct file.

Comment: The first autocommand (the one for `tex#PDFOpen()`) works great, but the second one is only executed when I close a buffer with `:bd`. If I have, for example, 3 buffers `foo.txt`, `bar.tex`, `baz.tex`, when I quit vim I'd expect `tex#PDFClose()` to be called on `bar.tex` and `baz.tex`. Also, why is it recommendable to put that autogroup in my general .vimrc (init.vim in my case)? Isn't filetype-related stuff supposed to be grouped under `ftplugin` in `<filetype>.vim` to have a simpler vimrc?

Comment: @noibe Are you sure BufDelete isn't called for those two? I think this might be the issue with `<afile>` I mentioned at the end... `%` will not necessarily point to the buffer being deleted. `:help BufDelete` mentions that.

Comment: Yes, generally you want to use ftplugin's to configure per-filetype settings, but setting additional autocmd's from there looks a little odd. It *might* work, but setting an autocmd for BufRead from the ftplugin won't work, since the BufRead command will already have happened at that point... You could just call PDFOpen directly from the ftplugin and add the per-buffer autocmd for BufDelete there, that might work. But I feel that matching `*.tex` on a pair of autocmd's is cleaner.

Comment: If you're doing global autocmd's, they can't be defined in a per-filetype plug-in that might be loaded too late, or multiple times... It doesn't *need* to be in your vimrc though, you could define it on a `plugin/*.vim` file too, that would work too.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure BufDelete isn't called. Even in simplest example, i.e. if I open a single tex file with `nvim foo.tex` without any other buffers, when I `:q` the .pdf file is still there, so `tex#PDFClose()` isn't called. In `tex#PDFClose()` the only time I use `%` is when defining the filepath with `let filepath = expand('%:p:r').'.pdf'`. I tried changing that to `let filepath = expand('<afile>:p:r').'.pdf'`, but it didn't work.

Comment: `BufDelete` is triggered on `:set nobuflisted` (also after `:bdelete`, as it implicitly does `set nobuflisted` also). "Loaded" state doesn't matter.