# Echo filename before deleting buffer

Tags: vimscript, neovim, buffers, autocmd

I would like to echo the filename before deleting any buffer (`:bd`, `:q`). I wanted to achieve this by using auto-commands like this:

```lua
augroup DummyCodeGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufDelete * lua print("path", vim.fn.expand('%:p'))
augroup END
```

But it seems like nothing is printed (just the "path" path). When I am just executing the following:

```lua
:lua print("path", vim.fn.expand('%:p'))
```

Then the right path is printed on the message line.

How can I achieve this? Should I use `BufUnload` instead as that's called before the `BufDelete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written under `:h BufDelete`

> NOTE: Current buffer "%" may be different from the buffer being deleted

And the same holds for about a half of auto-commands in Vim. Therefore, it must be `vim.fn.expand("<afile>:p")` instead.

> I would like to echo the filename before deleting any buffer (:bd, :q).

Note that `BufDelete` is only triggered before the option `buflisted` being switched to `nobuflisted`. See [this topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26217/run-autocmd-when-creating-deleting-a-buffer) for a more detailed explanation.